# How to answer a job application with a sealed record

Tags: unemployment

How would you answer these questions if your misdemeanor been sealed.       Have you ever been arrested?  Have you ever been convicted of a crime ?

Answer (score 0):

### Depends on what “sealed” means in that jurisdiction

It can mean that the record no longer appears on public facing information but the arrest and conviction are still things that can legally be considered if, for example, court. If so, the correct answer to those questions is “yes”.

In other jurisdictions the arrest and conviction are truly expunged - they are legally nullity. If so, the correct legal answer is “no”. However, while they never legally happened they did actually happen and, rightly or wrongly, someone who knows it happened might see that “no” as a lie.

Comment: It also depends on who's asking. In the US, for instance, you have to disclose sealed and expunged convictions for some jobs (like if you're applying to be a police officer).